# Можно вскинуть голову к кому-либо?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

> Но когда она решила апеллировать и ко мне, я притворилась, что ничего
>   не понимаю. Так удобней наблюдать. По моему разговору с официантами,
>   который я вела практически жестами, она сообразила, что я не владею
>   никакими языками. И хоть осталась недовольна моим образованием, тем не
>   менее она иногда приветно **вскидывала голову ко мне**, сверкая
>   ярко-зелёной оправой своих детских очков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, если этот кто-то пролетает вверху или лежит на верхней полке. Важно, чтобы направление "вскидывания" (оно всегда вверх, вдоль силовых линий поля гравитации) соответствовало контексту.

Answer (score 1):

И хоть осталась недовольна моим образованием, тем не менее она иногда приветно **вскидывала в мою сторону голову**, сверкая ярко-зелёной оправой своих детских очков.

Если голова перед этим была опущена (например, официантка делала записи), то она поднимала (вскидывала) голову и при этом поворачивала ее, чтобы взглянуть  на клиента.

**ВСКИНУТЬ,**  св. что. 1. Подняв, подбросив вверх, поместить где-л. В. рюкзак на спину. В. очки на нос (быстрым движением надеть очки). 2. Быстрым, резким движением поднять. В. ружьё. **В. голову.** В. уши (о животном). **В. глаза (быстро и прямо посмотреть на кого-, что-л.).**